# When to charge a car battery

Tags: battery

When is a good time to charge a car battery after getting a new car?

This is to avoid a dead car battery.

Comment: Unless you're just going to park you new car somewhere, driving it around on trips longer than, say, local grocery, ought to keep it fully charged.

Comment: @BillDOe How so? Doesn't that use up battery, like a remote controller consumes battery?

Comment: Hmm...guess I coulda worded that a bit better. Obviously, if you're going to just park your car, you'll have to keep it charged with some sort of battery charger as Jeffyx mentions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that everything is in good condition, you should rarely, if ever, need to charge the battery. As you are driving along, the alternator will charge the battery, and generally after about 5-10 miles of driving it should be fully charged again.

There are a few exceptions, such as if you frequently do very short journeys (especially in winter, when you also have lights, heaters etc on), or if the battery is reaching the end of it's life (5-8 years, depending on the local environment and usage patterns)

Answer (score 0):

I'm too new to comment, but you can get a Automatic Battery Float Charger for pretty cheap (around 10 bucks) they're designed to not over charge and it will keep you from having to run your car to keep it charged. It also helps with the life of the battery.